# How to put large int array into xml resource file?

Tags: android

I have a large number of integer constants. I want to put them in array. This array must be accesible from different activities. If I put this array to variable in MainActivity.java, there is a problem to access it from child activity. Putting them to resources (arrays.xml) is a bigger problem - each integer value must be "decorated" with this: "<item>1234</item>". There are couple of thousand integer values. So what is the best way to declare such array?

Comment: Why not just make a static array in some Constants class?

Comment: How to get array from that Constants class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with a static array like this :

```
private class MyClass {
    final static ArrayList<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

public MyClass(){
   this.mylist.add(1234);
   this.mylist.add(1284);
   ..........
 } 

 pblic ArrayList<Integer>  getmylist(){
  return this.mylist;
 }
```

And then in each **Activity** you need your list :

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
ArrayList<Integer> myList = myclass.getmylist();
```

Comment: A problem here is that  `myclass.getmylist().set(0, 3);` would change the value of the first constant, therefore they are not constants anymore as they can be modified

Comment: The get list method will return the list you already set in your constructor

Comment: yes and the elements of that list can then be modified, which is an undesired behaviour here as we want them to be constants

Comment: The elements could never be modified as there is no set method and also u don't pass parameters to the constructor . Your list will remain static and the only way to change their elements is by editing the list in your class

Comment: try my example:         MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = myclass.getmylist();
        myList.set(0, 3);
        System.out.println(myList.get(0));

It returns 3, not 1234.

Comment: Also your list is not static.

Comment: Yes you can add or remive an item but in only one scoop , but the list will always remain the same , u can add final static to it

Comment: even with final static as you just added my example still works, it does not make the list immutable. I think you do not know what static means.

Comment: Well , you can't stop a list for getting new item with set or add method :)

Comment: The only way you can do this is creating a new arraylist class that extends from ArrayList  and override the method set and add by null

Answer (score 0):

**You could make a private static unmodifiable final list on a class**
and have a public getter (and no setter)

I think it is important you make it both `final` and `unmodifiable` if it is going to hold constants, you don't want anything to be able to change the list itself or any of its values

```
public class Constants {
   private static final List<Integer> constantsArray = 
       Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

   public int getConstantAtIndex(int i) {
      return constantsArray.get(i);
   }
}
```

As you are returning an int, the list can't be modified.

**Or even have your integers as a comma separated string in a file**

```
public class Constants {
  private static final List<Integer> constantsArray = makeList();

  private static List<Integer> makeList() {
     List<Integer> list = readConstantsFromFile();
     return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
  }

  private static List<Integer> readConstantsFromFile() {
     // Read the file, and get the String ()
     String s = <comma spearated string from the file>  
     String[] a = s.split(",");
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
     for(String v : a) {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(v));
     }
     return list;
  }

  public int getConstantAtIndex(int i) {
     return constantsArray.get(i);
  }
}
```